# Excel - Perform Summation of Column of If Statements In One Cell

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, sumifs

I feel like I've done this before but am at a total loss after looking at a lot of pages already.

Consider a set of data given in two columns, x and y. X column is always ascending in value, y is random. I need a single cell to calculate the sum of a column of IF statements within a specified range of x without actually displaying the column of IF statements or using VBA. In other words: I want to turn this [(IMG1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46t32.jpg)  into this [(IMG2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdhrb.jpg)

In the first picture, the z column has this formula for each cell in a descending order: `=IF(AND(B2>0,A2>$D$2,A2<$D$3),A2-A1,0)`

I feel like I can use SUMIFS or an array formula somehow but I'm at a loss.

Please forgive if I improperly posted this somehow - this is my first post.

-Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **Array Formula** which requires a special key stroke **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

```
=SUM(IFERROR((A2:A11>0)*(B2:B11>0)*(A2:A11>D2)*(A2:A11<D3)*(A2:A11-A1:A10),0))
```

Confirm this formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Comment: YES THANK YOU!! Is the "iferror(...,0) to filter out the title lines not being numerical (and thus returning an error for that single cell)?

Comment: Actually I've come across another question now: I'm not entirely familiar with using asterisks in a SUM function. Can you explain why/how those are used in this case? (I understand the conditions they're describing, just confused on the syntax i.e. why they wouldn't be multiplying all that together).

Comment: * here denotes the multiplication.

Comment: Oh so I AM just literally multiplying these array statements that return 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE (unless it's not a logical expression like the last one)?

Comment: That's correct. The last one is the actual calculation which needs to be added. Just use the Evaluate Formula and you will get the logic. :)